# mysql galera and jpa

Tags: mysql, jpa, galera

I whould like to implement a scenario using jee/ejb/jpa with MySQL galera. 
Has anyone tried something similar?

I have 2 master MySQL nodes communicate with each other with galera.

I have the same application running on 2 wildfly application servers(cluster with 2 nodes) communicating with the each instance of galera cluster. I use jpa.

I have the 2 instances of mysql and wildfly in different geographic locations. 
The ping takes 250 ms betweeb the locations.

I'm looking for some mechanism to prevent from data inconsistency.
 a typical prolematic scenario is the following:

the first wilfly node writes to first mysql insatnce some data , galera replicates it to the second mysql instance and jpa doesn't know it.

Comment: please check this[URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: There is no easy answer here. You have to think about your data and accept the fact that at any given time the two mySql servers will be different. Be selective about what you are allowing JPA to cache and don't write code that absolutely needs new data to be available right away.